# Anchor Links on Parent Page that Jump To Different Sections in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, postmessage

I have a main parent page that I have set up with Page Section Name

When triggered I want the iFrame to slide down to that section inside of the iFrame. Is this possible? I know inside of the same page i could just create an ID with the same href="#ID" but I don't know where to begin with this. Any solutions or recommendations would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide your code please!

Answer (score 0):

You can give the IFRAME a `name` attribute, and the link a `target` attribute that points to that particular name. Here's an example:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
a, iframe {
  margin: 0 16px 8px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <a href="https://vuejs.org/#hero" target="my-iframe">
      Go to the top in the IFRAME
    </a>
    <a href="https://vuejs.org/#footer" target="my-iframe">
      Go to the footer in the IFRAME
    </a>
  </div>

  <iframe name="my-iframe" src="https://vuejs.org/" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
</div>
```

Note that I'm providing the full URL `https://vuejs.org/#footer` in the HREF attribute, not just `#footer`; the shorthand version only works if the link target is in the same document. As long as the URL before the `#` doesn't change, the browser will still only scroll to the named target, not reload the frame.

Comment: Hmm this method isn't working for me. I'm just getting a 404 with the links.